# Best place for Mint Questions?

Tags: discussion

sorry if this is the wrong place to post this; but I just got my first computer running linux mint, and have some questions.

What would be the best place to ask them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome!

This site is a good place to ask questions relating to Linux Mint ([the main site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), not this Meta site).

If your question is related to Linux Mint *specifically*, then add the [linux-mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) tag to the question along with any other tags that are relevant. If it's not specific to the distribution, but to Linux, then add the [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag.  Otherwise, depending on what the question is about, just add the appropriate tags (e.g. [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) for questions relating to parsing text files).  Other users may re-tag your question if appropriate (so don't worry about it).

Please also see [The Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) about asking questions.